# unterminated string on DataTables JSON encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have a issue when I try to use `DataTables` JQuery plugin.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 1572865 of the JSON data
```

I think it's the way that I encode my JSON from a large database cut in 3000 rows query, because if I do it in one time I get an **out of memory** error:

```
$rowNum = $this->db->query("SELECT ID WHERE CONDITION")->result_array();
$pas = 3000;
for($i = $rowNum[0]; $i < count($rowNum); $i = $i+$pas) { // Loop wrinting rows 3000 per 3000 in a JSON
    $begin = $rowNum[$i];
    $end = (empty($rowNum[$i+($pas-1)])) ? end($rowNum) : $rowNum[$i+($pas-1)];
    $query = "
            LARGE QUERY FOR HAVING THE WHOLE TABLE AND ID BETWEEN {$begin} AND {$end} ";
    $rows = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    $line = json_encode($rows);
    file_put_contents(FCPATH."application/ajax/GuyaforTable_brut.json", $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
$charMappings = [
    '][' => ',',
];
$content = file_get_contents(FCPATH."application/ajax/GuyaforTable_brut.json");
file_put_contents(FCPATH."application/ajax/GuyaforTable_brut.json", strtr($content, $charMappings));
```

Line 1 column 1572865 of the JSON :

```
... 
,{"NomForet":"Paracou","n_parcelle":"17","n_carre":"2","n_arbre":"1081.0","Surface":"6.25","i_arbre":"167370","X":"232.0","Y":"156.0",
"Xutm":"272952.1 -> 6 <- ",
"Yutm":"586592.38","UTMZone":"22","Lat":"5.3035345","Lon":"-53.048702","n_essence":"751","nomPilote":"mesupu","Densite":"1.1000000000000001","circonf":"60.0","code_vivant":"1","code_mesure":"0","campagne":"1995","circ_corr":"60.0","code_corr":"0","Famille":"Melastomataceae","Genre":"Miconia","Espece":"tschudyoides","Commerciale":"0","SourceBota":"Vern","indSurete":"-1.0"},{"NomForet"
...
```

Comment: For what purpose do you make such json? Maybe csv file will be more suitable?

Comment: For an ajax pagination with datatables https://datatables.net/manual/ajax, this is a large database and I need to use the datatables plugin.

Comment: The out of memory error is PHP hitting the max allowed memory allocation. Editing the server's php.ini more memory can be allowed. However, there is performance implications to take into consideration. IMO, multiple smaller queries would be better. As for the `unterminated string` error, the JSON is not properly formatted. If you can get the return data run it through json-lint.com or other synbtax checkers. My guess is an unescaped quote or similar special character.

Comment: Yes, I tried to change the max allowed memory allocation, but I think the database is too large, I reached the out of memory error when apache was using 1,7go I think it is the max allowed by the OS, because I changed apache max RAM allowed too. Thank you for jsonlint.com I searched a tool like this for this issue.

Comment: "Valid JSON" for jsonlint.com

Comment: Ok, the issue is not about JSON encoding, this is about reading the JSON, it is too large for JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you, but if you were getting that error inside Firefox devtools it seems that will be fixed in the upcoming version (61): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223726

The devtools was truncating responses over a certain size (not affecting the actual code).

Comment: This is very useful. I tested the Ajax call and the devtool truncates the response. After I sent the request via PostMan I was able to see the entire response.